# python mysql - is commit() required for SELECT?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a very simple python code getting some data from mysql:

```
    version = 1
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        query = f'select latest_version from version'
        cur.execute(query)
        for row in cur:
            version = int(row[0])      
    cur.close()
    print(version)
```

That code is executed from AWS Lambda accessing my private mysql instance (but none of that should matter imho).

It was working perfectly fine, then i have updated version values in DB using SQL:

```
UPDATE version set latest_version=11;
COMMIT;
FLUSH TABLES;
```

The problem: after running above SQL code when i run my python code i was getting the old value from DB (10 instead of 11), like some caching....

Now when i have added to my python code commit() like this:

```
    version = 1
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        query = f'select latest_version from version'
        cur.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        for row in cur:
            version = int(row[0])      
    cur.close()
    print(version)
```

It all started to work fine and i got a new version.

This problem occurred for me several times with different SQL tables (and had to use above "workaround"). Always the same results, tested many times.

I have quite some other code operating on that DB running a lot of inserts on other tables (but i never insert on version table via python code). Also i am quite intensive running those workers in many parallel threads operating on the same DB as the same time (but no dependencies, should not have any deadlocks, all workers finishing work in time).

Could you please help me understand why this is happening ?

One of my guesses was that i did not close connections to mysql correctly in other scripts, but in such case i guess i would run out of connections/db hanlders(workers) and would not be able to connect anymore, not get cached values....So i am clueless here. Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your default transaction isolation is REPEATABLE-READ, so repeated queries in the same transaction never see an updated view of the database.

If you start a new transaction, queries will read current data as of the time you start your transaction.

You could alternatively set your transaction isolation to READ-COMMITTED, so your SELECT always sees the current committed data. Do the following before you do your first query:

```
cur.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
```

If that doesn't work, then do one COMMIT after changing the isolation level.

You don't need to do FLUSH TABLES in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill, let me test & confirm.

Comment: Still: i run python script many times, it's not the same transaction, each time i have new connection, new cursor and still the old value (which has been updated in DB 30 minutes earlier -> mysql client showing the current value). How is that possible ?

Comment: I think it's acting as designed for REPEATABLE-READ transactions. Your first SELECT of the transaction establishes a stable snapshot of the database, so anything committed after that will not be visible (until you start a new transaction, which sets a new snapshot). I recommend reading this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: but my case is different. I change something in DB and commit it. And do confirm it's committed. Only AFTER that (30 min later) i do run my python script and still see the old version (and my python script is building a new conn, not caching anything).

Comment: i do believe it might be related to AWS Lambda connection reuse. I do configure mysql connection outside of handler() so it's reused by each warm Lambda. Still the cursor is new and should return the current value (committed in the past).

Comment: But if it still has a connection from a previous lambda execution, it could still have a transaction open from that earlier time. That's rather disturbing, because it means the lambda can leak data across invocations.

Comment: But in Lambda handler() i always do create a new cursor and close it. So cursor is not shared across lambda executions, only connection. In such case we should not leak transactions - is that correct Bill ? Ohhhh, indeed you might be correct here.....good catch, i need to do more testing.

Comment: An easy test is to issue a `conn.commit()` as the first thing you do in the lambda, before you do the query. That will force a new transaction to start.

Comment: You are correct Bill, confirmed, indeed looks like i need to do conn.commit() as the first thing in Lambda, even if that lambda is only doing selects (not inserts). That's quite concerning for me and i do agree with you we have a generic issue with the design here, but at least it solves my problem (will have to do scale testing at some point). Many thanks for your help Bill !!!